# Github separate application layers

Tags: heroku, github, deployment

I am working on a small app and I have a typical MVC design structure. Thus, all my front-end is located inside a special directory that is separated from actual back-end code and DB scripts. I use heroku to deploy from github. But recently I had a designer to join in and I would like to give designed ability to push into ONLY designer related folder on my github project. Is it possible to do so? If not, is it possible to organize some sort of abstraction between different folders in heroku?

Thanks!